# Formula keeps saying that there are too many arguments?

Tags: excel

```
=IF(
    (        AND(
            'Subject Teachers'!X4 <> "",
            'Subject Teachers'!T4 >= 70
        ) ),
    'Subject Teachers'!T4,
    'Subject Teachers'!R4,
    IF(
        (            AND(
                'Subject Teachers'!R4 <> "",
                'Subject Teachers'!O4 >= 70
            ) ),
        'Subject Teachers'!O4,
        'Subject Teachers'!L4,
        IF(
            (                AND(
                    'Subject Teachers'!L4 <> "",
                    'Subject Teachers'!I4 >= 70
                ) ),
            'Subject Teachers'!I4,
            "N/A"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Your first two `IF` statements have 4 arguments. Not sure what you are trying to do there. The first statement reads "IF both X4 is not equal to nothing AND T4 is greater than or equal to 70, then T4, Else R4... Then there is another if statement hanging out in the fourth non-existing parameter of your if statement"

Answer (score 0):

You have to many in the first IF statement. an if statement has 3 sections. The test, result if true and result if false. Your statement continues after the result is false.

Generic if statement example:

if(, , )

You have added an and statement in the . That goes from AND('Subject Teachers'!X4<>"",'Subject Teachers'!T4>=70)). So if x4 is not blank and t4 is greater than or equal to 70 then true else fase. Your statement has if the and statement is true then make it equal the value in 'Subject Teachers'!T4.

However if it is false make it equal to 'Subject Teachers'!T4. That should be the end. However you have another if statement beginning.

Depending what you are trying to do you should place the next if statement in the true section or the false section.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your formula "work" by removing the "else/otherwise" results from the first two `IFs`, like this:

```
=IF(AND('Subject Teachers'!X4<>"",'Subject Teachers'!T4>=70),'Subject Teachers'!T4,IF(AND('Subject Teachers'!R4<>"",'Subject Teachers'!O4>=70),'Subject Teachers'!O4,IF(AND('Subject Teachers'!L4<>"",'Subject Teachers'!I4>=70),'Subject Teachers'!I4,"N/A")))
```

That removes the results `L4` and `R4`.

The original formula is impossible because it says, for example, **"if X then do THIS, otherwise do THIS, and if Y then do THIS, otherwise do THIS, and if Z then do THIS, otherwise do THIS"**. See, there are *three* results from that statement - it can't return a single answer. A typical nested IF formula goes **"if X then do THIS, otherwise if Y then do THIS, otherwise if Z then do THIS, otherwise do THIS"**. That's what the edited formula above does.

Alternatively, if you do want all three results then you can nest the results together, like this:

```
=IF(AND('Subject Teachers'!X4<>"",'Subject Teachers'!T4>=70),'Subject Teachers'!T4,'Subject Teachers'!R4)&"-"&IF(AND('Subject Teachers'!R4<>"",'Subject Teachers'!O4>=70),'Subject Teachers'!O4,'Subject Teachers'!L4)&"-"&IF(AND('Subject Teachers'!L4<>"",'Subject Teachers'!I4>=70),'Subject Teachers'!I4,"N/A")
```

This simply combines the three results, separated by hyphens. So the result would be something like `80-90-50`.